# How will i use flag emoji in tablepress of wordpress blog?

Tags: html-table, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to import an excel file in Wordpress blog using Tablepress with all the county name along with its flag. I am solving this using pandas(python) but i am not able to do. Is there any way to add flag along with country name without picking individually because there are so many countries and i can not add flag emoji one by one.

The following table is the part of original table that i want to create in wordpress.

```
Country           Population (1973)      Population (2023)     Change (1973–2023)
 China          881,652,084            1,425,671,353         544,019,269
 India          596,107,487            1,428,627,666         832,520,179
 United States  207,314,772            339,996,567           132,681,795
 Russia         132,191,636            144,444,360           12,252,724
 Indonesia      124,709,060.           777,534,118           152,825,058
 Japan          109,679,473            123,294,516           13,615,043
```